# How does Order by affect assignment when used along with COALESCE

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, coalesce

I have a T-SQL variable to which I am assigning a value using `SELECT` operation. Since the "SELECT" query might return multiple rows therefore I am using COALESCE function which appends all the values separated by a comma. So far all good and query is behaving as intended. But when I try to order my values using order by clause only one row is appended to variable.

Why adding Order By clause in Query 2 produces so different result then Query 1?

**[Results 1]**:

> Ball 1,Ball 2,Bat 3,Bat 1,Bat 2

**[Results 2]**:

> Bat 1

JS Fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8dad1/15

[SQL Fiddle][1]

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Trans
([Id] int, [Instrument] varchar(20), [Trans_Type] int, [Quantity] int);

CREATE TABLE tbl_Trans_Type
([Id] int, [Trans_Type] varchar(20));  

INSERT INTO tbl_Trans  ([Id], [Instrument], [Trans_Type], [Quantity])

VALUES  
(1,'Ball 1', 121, 50),
(2,'Ball 2', 121, 20),
(3,'Bat 3', 122, 1000),
(4,'Bat 1', 124, 400),
(5,'Bat 2', 121, 300);


INSERT INTO tbl_Trans_Type  ([Id], [Trans_Type])

VALUES 
(121,'Buy'),
(122,'Sell'),
(123,'ReSell'),
(124,'Rent')

**Query 1**:

DECLARE @ST VARCHAR(500) = NULL
SELECT @ST = COALESCE(@ST+ ',' , '')+Instrument 
FROM tbl_Trans a
LEFT JOIN tbl_Trans_Type b on a.Trans_Type = b.Id 

SELECT @ST
```

**[Results 1]**:

> ```
> | Ball 1,Ball 2,Bat 3,Bat 1,Bat 2 |
> ```

**Query 2**:

```
DECLARE @ST2 VARCHAR(500) = NULL
SELECT  @ST2 = COALESCE(@ST2+ ',' , '')+Instrument 
FROM tbl_Trans a
LEFT JOIN tbl_Trans_Type b on a.Trans_Type = b.Id 
ORDER BY IIF(b.Trans_Type='Buy',1,2)

SELECT  @ST2
```

**[Results 2]**:

> ```
> | Bat 1 |
> ```

Comment: There is a [warning about trying to do this in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql#remarks) (I've often stated that I think it's located in the *wrong* doc, but it's been there forever): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values [...] This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are **not guaranteed to be executed exactly once** for each output row"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is by design. Using assignment operations (concatenation in this scenario) in queries with ORDER BY clause has undefined behavior.

use the following query for successful conversion of rows into comma separated values with order by clause

```
select stuff((select ','+Instrument 
FROM tbl_Trans a
  LEFT JOIN tbl_Trans_Type b on a.Trans_Type = b.Id 
ORDER BY IIF(b.Trans_Type='Buy',1,2)
for xml path('')) ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: It's documented to be undefined even in the absence of `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks Nandish and Damien-The-Unbeliever for helping out. I was really confused about this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to concatenate but with ordering:

```
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' +Instrument 
        FROM tbl_Trans a
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Trans_Type b 
            on a.Trans_Type = b.Id 
        ORDER BY IIF(b.Trans_Type='Buy',1,2)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);
```