# SQL Server: Assign to different Variables depending on the column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `user_config` that stores code names and values.

For example, something like this:

| id | code | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sam | ctr | HK |
| sam | curr | HKD |
| sam | altcurr | EUR,USD |

```
declare
    @country varchar(2),
    @currency varchar(3),
    @alternate_currencies varchar(100);

select @country = u.value
from user_config u
where u.code = 'ctr'
  and u.id = 'sam';

select @currency = u.value
from user_config u
where u.code = 'curr'
  and u.id = 'sam';

select @alternate_currencies = u.value
from user_config u
where u.code = 'altcurr'
  and u.id = 'sam';
```

Is there a way to assign variables in one SQL, depending on the value of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CASE expressions will help you here

```
select @country = (case when u.code = 'ctr' then u.value else @country end),
       @currency = (case when u.code = 'curr' then u.value else @currency end),
       @alternate_currencies = (case when u.code = 'altcurr' then u.value else @alternate_currencies end)
  from user_config u
 where u.id = 'sam';
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70774cedc86ed2747ea8a67361dbe7ca)

Comment: `case` _expressions_.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer given by @ekochergin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69894563/14868997) has [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282901/how-does-order-by-affect-assignment-when-used-along-with-coalesce), because it is using variable coalescing to aggregate. Instead, use normal conditional aggregation, and *then* assign to variables

```sql
select @country = MIN(case when u.code = 'ctr' then u.value end),
       @currency = MIN(case when u.code = 'curr' then u.value end),
       @alternate_currencies = MIN(case when u.code = 'altcurr' then u.value end)
  from user_config u
 where u.id = 'sam';
```